# Notification won't Vibrate

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing a simple Notification demo in Android Studio where there's a button in the main activity and when you click it, a notification comes up which leads to another activity on click. I setVibrate on the notification obj but there's no vibrate. Not sure if the pattern is off or not.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int id = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);

}


public void notificationMethod(View v){

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notification.setTicker("this is ticker");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle("This is the Title");
    notification.setContentText("This is the Text");
    notification.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000} );


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pintent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(id, notification.build());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the vibrate permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Side-note: On Android M, you do not have to request this at runtime, it is a normal permission.

You can read more about normal permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html).

Comment: I put that permission in but still no vibration when notification was made

Comment: @reallenliu Could you have placed it in the wrong area of the manifest? I used to have lots of issues doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that the mobile is connected to the cable, and the vibration is ignored, without cable testing